# 2D Integral and normal distribution

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I would like to calculate $$E(1_{\{a \leq m+ vX \leq b\}}1_{\{c \leq n+ w(\rho X+ \sqrt{1-\rho^2} Y) \leq d\}})$$

where $ -1 \leq \rho \leq 1$ , $v>0, w >0, a<b, c<d$ and $X,Y$ normally distributed centered with variance 1, independent.

This expectation can be written as a double integral of the form 
$$\int_{m_1}^{m_2}[\Phi(m_3-\alpha_3x)-\Phi(m_4-\alpha_4x)] f_X(x)dx$$

where $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,\alpha_3$ and $\alpha_4$ are functions of the initial parameters. $f_X$ is the density function of a normal(reduced and centered) variable.

WHat is next then ? Is there a closed-form formula for that ?

Comment: For some $\alpha,\beta,\alpha',\beta'$,

\begin{align}
E\left(\mathbf1_{a\le m+vX\le b\,,\,c\le n+w(\rho X+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,Y)\le d}\right)
&=P\left(\alpha\le X\le\beta\,,\,\alpha'\le \rho X+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,Y\le \beta'\right)
\\&=P\left(\alpha\le X\le \beta\,,\,\frac{\alpha'-\rho X}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\le Y\le \frac{\beta'-\rho X}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right)
\\\\&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}\int_{(\alpha'-\rho x)/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}^{(\beta'-\rho x)/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}\,dy\,dx
\end{align}

At this point you might use a polar transformation.

Comment: Polar transformation would work well , if the space of integration is a triangle . However, in most cases, it is a parallelogram